# Determining functional dependencies from an ER diagram

Tags: database, database-design, functional-dependencies, erd

I have to determine the functional dependencies for the below ER:
[image]

As shown It's a one-to-many relationship. Depending on the functional dependency definition:

> "X->Y means,  each possible value of X can correspond to exactly one
>   value of Y"

, I can write:

```
A -> B
P -> Q,R
```

But I'm not sure how should the FD should be written for Ent1 and Ent1 with the relation. If I write `A -> X,P`is it correct?. Can someone explain?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. What does your textbook say? What does it say the numbers say? What does a bubble on a diamond means? A box? What does "one-to-many relationship" mean? What does that have to do with "each possible value of X can correspond to exactly one value of Y"? Why A -> B & P -> Q,R? Why would you write  A -> X,P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any relationship, the combination of entity sets in many-roles determine the other entity sets and attributes in the relationship.

In your example, `Ent2` (represented by `P`) determines `Ent1` (represented by `A`) as well as `X`.

So, you would write `P -> A,X`.

Comment: Yes if the participation cardinalities are classic Chen look-across. Sadly yet another diagram without a legend.

Comment: In the diagram, an instance of `Ent2` may or may not be in relationship with an instance of `Ent1`. If it is, given its value of `P`, the values for `A` and `X` are determined. What happens if it does not? Which values of `A` and `X` does `P` determine? Are they NULL? Is NULL even allowed in ER?

Comment: @ingomueller.net The diagram represents 3 relations: `P -> Q, R`, `A -> B` and `P -> A, X`. The first two relations are entity relations in Chen's terminology, while the third is a relationship relation. The question and answer pertained to what determines what within the relationship relation. This relation doesn't need to be left-total and NULL is not required.